# Image Upload Failed in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Write Following Code for to Upload Image in Joomla Project. that code is Working for Previous Sites but Still Now Not Working this Code.

```
if($_FILES["photo1"]["type"]=="image/png"){

              $path='/media/matri/profiles/pending/watermark-K'.$id.'_pho_1.png';   
    }

    if($_FILES["photo1"]["type"]=="image/jpeg"){

              $path='/media/matri/profiles/pending/watermark-K'.$id.'_pho_1.jpeg';  

    }

    if($_FILES["photo1"]["type"]=="image/jpg"){

              $path='/media/matri/profiles/pending/watermark-K'.$id.'_pho_1.jpg';   
    }

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo1"]["tmp_name"], $path)
```

Comment: I also check the Directory is writeable....

Comment: Do a var_dump($_FILES["photo1"]["tmp_name"]) ; var_dump($path); exit; and paste the result here. Put the code before move_uploaded_file.

Answer (score 0):

Change Media Folder Group/Owner Permission to www-data